# How to disable image scaling in ContentFlow?

Tags: javascript, image, contentflow

I am using [ContentFlow](http://jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) with gallery2 addon.

I don't like default image scaling of gallery2, so I want to modify this addon, but first I would like to turn off image scaling in slides.

How can I do it?